# How to import website data which has an unknow format?

Tags: import

I want to import data from this website: http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006;

It should look like

> ```
> var hq_str_sh601006= "大秦铁路,13.13,12.87,13.37,13.77,12.95,13.38,13.39,356310317,4776670723,1630,13.38,21200,13.37,62186,13.36,104760,13.35,152300,13.34,71700,13.39,55056,13.40,24100,13.41,39400,13.42,22366,13.43,2015-04-17,15:03:06,00";"
> ```

but when I input

```
Import["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006"]
```

the output is `$Failed`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Import` has trouble with the character encoding on my computer:

```
Import["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006", "HTML"]
(* "var hq_str_sh601006="`óÇØÌúÂ·,13.13,12.87,13.37,13.77,12.95,13.38, [...] ;" *)
```

We can find the encoding by looking at the HTML headers:

```
Grid@URLFetch["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006", "Headers"]
```

> ```
> Cache-Control   no-cache
> Content-Length  239
> Connection      Keep-Alive
> Content-Type    application/x-javascript; charset=GBK
> ```

[`"GBK"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) is not one of the possible `$CharacterEncodings`.  We can try all possible encodings to see if any work:

```
Grid[Table[{e, 
   Import["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006", "Text", 
    CharacterEncoding -> e]}, {e, $CharacterEncodings}]]
```

I find that [`"CP936"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936) and [`"MacintoshChineseSimplified"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-CN) work:

```
Import["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006", "HTML", CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"]
(* var hq_str_sh601006="大秦铁路,13.13,12.87,13.37,13.77,12.95,13.38,13.39 [...] "; *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that

```
Import["http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=sh601006", "HTML"]
```

works.

Comment: I have found that `"Text"` works well on unformatted data.